# Storing C# Converted base64 as SQL Server varbinary(max)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've got an angular webapp where I accept images in base64 and store them in T-SQL varbinary. However, I have existing data stored in SQL-Server that appears to be in a different binary. I need both binaries to work with the same Read/Update methods in C#.

In the service I'm trying to convert a base64 string to SQL Server's varbinary and vice versa.

Manually in SSMS, I can take just the base64 string and insert into a row like this:

```
Cast(@base64ImgStr as varbinary(max))
```

But the result is different when I try to insert from C#:

```
Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
```

(same input). Since the binary is different the image doesn't show. I need a method in C# that provides the same binary as the one in T-SQL.

I must be around the solution, since I can cast and get the proper base64 in SQL Server (again, not in C#) like this:

```
cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@source"))', 'varchar(max)')
```

Instead of base64 I get back Unicode symbols, otherwise I'd paste in an example.

I need to get the base64 without calling the SQL Server base64Binary method, because my service reads images like this:

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(varbinary)
```

If I convert the manually inserted varbinary (Cast(@base64ImgStr as varbinary(max))) into varchar(max), I get a base64 string and the image displays appropriately in my webapp.
But, this is not so when I use the C# method to create the binary. With the type of varbinary I get from Convert.FromBase64String(base64), I need an intermediate conversion in SQL Server (xs:base64binary) to reverse the binary to base64. With no intermediate conversion I get Unicode symbols and no image displays in the webapp. I don't want an intermediate conversion because I want consistent results whether users upload images or someone inserts images manually.

I don't see a method on the Convert class that gives me the same type of binary. But that seems to be exactly what I need. I suspect Unicode. Please help!

Comment: To store the image itself the result of `Convert.FromBase64String(base64);` should be stored. `Cast(@base64ImgStr as varbinary(max))` would store a binary representation of the base64 encoded image - are you decoding from/using base64 when you read back?

Comment: here's what i do to store the updated image: `pm.SponsorImg = Convert.FromBase64String(vm.sponsorImg);` (continuing answer - brb)

Comment: so i believe i am storing the result of `Convert.FromBase64String(base64)`. but that byte array does not show the same varbinary as is stored when i take the same image and do `Cast(@base64ImgStr as varbinary(max))`. here's how i'm reading it back: `var base64 = pm.SponsorImg != null ? Encoding.ASCII.GetString(pm.SponsorImg) : String.Empty;
` I need to continue to be able to read back this way because images will be both converted manually and uploaded via angular.

Comment: still seems to me that i need a method that converts base64 to SQL Server's base64binary, rather than the binary that is the result of the method I used on convert. is this possible in one method? if not, how else can i do it? i don't know the difference between each varbinary - but it seems one has an extra step of being converted to base64binary before being converted to varchar.

Comment: You seem to be going wrong with `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(varbinary)`. If varbinary is your data and you want a base64 encoded string you should just use `Convert.ToBase64String` to convert the byte array to. What you have says that the binary input is the binary representation of a string (ie the bytes represent ascii characters, not base64 encoded bytes).

Comment: remember that i have existing images that were manually inserted by turning the base64 into binary as follows: `Cast(@base64ImgStr as varbinary(max))`. the `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(varbinary)` returns the appropriate image that is displayed correctly (and if i `convert(varchar(max), @source)` i can see the base64 in ssms). because i need to ensure that these manually inserting images still work while also accepting new images, it would seem i need something in C# that is exactly the same varbinary as what i get from sql-server: `xs:base64Binary` above.

Comment: i need to adhere to the current varbinary type as created by sql. but i don't know how to get that same type with c#. perhaps i just don't follow, but i can't see how altering my read method from `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(varbinary)` will continue to work for existing images (stored by casting in sql server).

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/338068/chris , it seems that you provided the answer. i'm sorry i did not understand your recommendation at first. not sure how to give you more credit - thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
var image = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(image);
hex = hex.Replace("-", "");
hex = "0x" + hex;
```

This hex can be saved in a `varbinary(MAX)` field without casting or converting  and will show as an image in the browser.

Comment: Is there a PHP equivalent to this?

Comment: I am not aware.